# Why do I get an exception when I did not cross the limit?

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

Having re tweeted only 15 tweets, I get an exception saying.

```
403:The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error
message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due
to update limits (https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits
-update-api-dm-and-following).

message - Not authorized to use this endpoint.
code - 37

Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=b029ad3d or
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=132d0e3b
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[b029ad3d-132d0e3b], statusCode=403, message=Not authorized to use this endpoint., code=37, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.6-SNAPSHOT(build: afd755d42f0c2fd7a2a87cedf1e91e123de2d754)}
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:162)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:61)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.post(HttpClientWrapper.java:98)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.post(TwitterImpl.java:2023)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.retweetStatus(TwitterImpl.java:283)
    at org.tester.TweetSearcher.processRequest(TweetSearcher.java:73)
    at org.tester.TweetSearcher.doGet(TweetSearcher.java:100)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

What could be the reason for this ? How actually does the limit work ?

Java Code that re tweets :

```
            do {
            QueryResult result = twitter.search(new Query("#naples "));
            List<Status> statusList = result.getTweets();
            while(i.hasNext()) {
                Status s = (Status) i.next();
                long id = s.getId();
                c = new Counter();
                int totalUpdates = c.getUpdateCount();

                if(totalUpdates <= 30) { // continue to retweet
                    if(!s.isRetweeted() && !s.isRetweetedByMe()) {
                        twitter.retweetStatus(id);
                        totalUpdates++;
                        c.setUpdateCount(totalUpdates);
                    }
                } else { // Daily Limit Reached
                    limitReached = true;
                }
            }
        } while(!limitReached);
```

Comment: The error message gives you two Google links, and I quote: "Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=b029ad3d or
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=132d0e3b". Have you read the links? They contain useful information that likely answers your question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels They contain nothing useful

Comment: @SuhailGupta How many times have you run this program to test it, and what other sources of tweets do you have besides your test program? Have you truly only made 15 tweets today?

Comment: @JasonC yeah and my test twitter account has only made 63 tweets so far

Comment: @JasonC Should there be a gap between re tweets ? Like the code above will keep on re tweeting for the particular hash tag.

Comment: What your application is trying to do appears very strange — are you really just blindly retweeting anything that contains your target hashtag? That's incredibly obnoxious, spammy behavior, and it's entirely possible that Twitter is trying to explicitly prevent it here.

Comment: @duskwuff But why does it always print an exception after re tweeting 15 tweets ? Not more not less..

Comment: @SuhailGupta It sounds like a rate limit of some kind but a read of their documentation does not describe a rate limit. I can't really answer your question because I'm not familiar with the twitter API, sorry. I just asked you that question to get some clarifying info that might help others answer. Does it help if you delay between tweets? If you don't get a definitive answer here you may want to see if [Twitter support](https://support.twitter.com/forms) can shed some light on possible rate limits (and if they do, posting the answer back here could help people with the same question!).

Answer (score 1):

You must look at this [Automation rules and best practices](http://support.twitter.com/groups/33-report-a-violation/topics/121-guidelines-best-practices/articles/76915-automation-rules-and-best-practices) page.

> Automated retweeting of other users
>
> We discourage the automatic retweeting of other users based on a
>   particular keyword and may suspend accounts that engage in this
>   behavior, particularly if they are being frequently blocked and
>   reported as spam.

Btw, i guess you must give some function like sleep() to delay for every re-tweet.